# Spring creating beans of same interface

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

Consider a package which many classes all implement an interface `Policy`. The Policy has one method `canAccess`. There are 100+ policies like `MenNotAllowedPolicy` , `ChiledNotAllowedPolicy` ,... which all implement `Policy`

A property file describe which policies are applied to which service, for example:

```
BarrowBook=MenNotAllowedPolicy
BarrowMovie=MenNotAllowedPolicy,ChiledNotAllowedPolicy
```

To uses these polices there is a simple loop, which gets a service name an person, loop the property file and run the polices for persons. The main part of this code is:

```
public canPersonAccessService(aPerson , aService){
  //the listPolicy will be read from property file
  for(String policyClassName: listPolicy){        
      Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("foo.bar.Policies"+ policyClassName);
      Policy policy = (policy) clazz.newInstance();
      policy.canAccess(aPerson);
  }
}
```

Although Ii can make better by catching the Policy classes but I wonder if it is possible to do it easier with Spring ?! I decided a HashMap with `ClassName` as a key and the `class instance` as value, but how can I create it ?!

This a mimic of my problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define an interface called `Policy` as base interface for all policy implementations

```
interface Policy {
    boolean canAccess(User u);
}
```

Have one Spring Bean for each of the policy implementations - make sure you name the bean in `@Component` and ensure that it matches the name used in your properties file

```
@Component("MenNotAllowedPolicy")
public static class MenNotAllowedPolicy implements Policy {
    public boolean canAcces(User u) {
      ...
    }
}
```

Make the class that checks the policies also a Spring Bean, and have Spring `ApplicationContext` autowired in it

```
@Component
public static class PolicyChecker {
    ...
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext appContext;
    ...
    public boolean canPersonAccessService(User person, ....) {
       for(String policyName: listPolicy) { 
          Policy policy = appContext.getBean(policyName, Policy.class);
        ....
        policy.canAccess(person);
        ....
      }
    }
}
```

We look up policy by the its bean name, while also ensuring that bean implements Policy interface as indicated by second parameter of `getBean` method.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Why a hasmap while the ApplicationContext can do it all :) Thanks!